# Blurry icon when launching google-chrome with flag --app

Tags: google-chrome, elementary-os

Whenever I launch *google-chrome* browser with the *--app* flag, the corresponding icon of the browser appears blurry.

```
google-chrome --app=https://google.com
```

[image]